# Method with parameter of method reference that has nested method

Tags: typescript

I need to have method that takes reference to other method that might have nested one inside. All methods belongs to same object. Following code explains everything what I want to do:

```
class SomeClass {

  functionPop(this.mainFunc);

  functionPop(func) {
    func();
  }
  mainFunc() {
    console.log('This will be printed');
    this.nestedFunc(); //Here is an error
  }
  nestedFunc() {
    console.log('We didnt reach this point');
  }

}
```

The error says to me that there is a problem that this is undefined. I understand that word "this" in method mainFunc doesnt refer to object of SomeClass. I know I can fix it doing something like this:

```
class SomeClass {

  functionPop(this.mainFunc);

  functionPop(func,nestedFunction) {
    func(nestedFunction);
  }
  mainFunc(nestFunc) {
    console.log('This will be printed');
    nestedFunction();
  }
  nestedFunc() {
    console.log('Here we are successfully - this will be printed');
  }

}
```

I feel that it's so far from right solution, any ideas how to make this better - without these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you pass a function reference like this `functionPop(this.mainFunc);`, the context (`this`) inside the function changes based on how it is called. In this case it is called without a context inside `functionPop` as `func()` -- so `this` will be `undefined`.

To fix this you can wrap your functions with an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) when you are passing them -- this will preserve the context:

```
functionPop(() => this.mainFunc());
```

Or use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to set the context:

```
functionPop(this.mainFunc.bind(this));
```

Also see: [Red Flags for `this`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#red-flags-for-this).

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript 'this' could be different according to the call context. In your case you're losing call context, that's why errors appear.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Use arrow functions. In opposite to usual ones they don't create
   own context (ES6 feature).
2. Use 'bind' for binding needed context.

For more details with examples and pros/cons for possible options check this link:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript